# Standard deviation of uncertain values with known variances

Tags: standard-deviation, measurement-error

I have measurements $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N$ that have unknown measurement errors $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \ldots, \epsilon_N$ but known variances $\sigma^2_1, \sigma^2_2, \ldots, \sigma^2_N$. The x's can be assumed to be drawn from a "Normal" distribution with means $\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_N$ with the caveats that

(1) the $x$'s are correlated with each other (and their correlations are known),

(2) the $\sigma$'s are correlated with each other (unknown - but maybe I could figure it out), and

(3) the $\sigma$'s are correlated with the $\mu$'s (unknown - but maybe I could figure it out).

What is the standard deviation of $x$?

A numerical (Monte Carlo) solution is fine for me. In particular, a normal thing for me to do is to draw samples from a normal distribution and take the standard deviation of those samples. However, I do not know how to deal with the possible correlations, as I am afraid that the assumption of them being uncorrelated would lead me to the wrong result here.

Comment: are the $\epsilon$'s uncorrelated with the $x$'s?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, they could be - but could you please consider both cases? I should mention that a numerical (Monte Carlo) solution would be acceptable to me too. I just don't really know how to deal with the restriction that they are all possibly correlated.

Comment: I'm presently seeking a question sufficiently clear that it is answerable, so you should edit your question to be precise about what you want.

Comment: @Glen_b OK - I have edited the question.